# Что значит окружение пользователя в node.js ?

Tags: node.js

Что значит окружение пользователя в node.js.  Встерит строку

```
var host = process.env['MONGO_NODE_DRIVER_HOST'] != null process.env['MONGO_NODE_DRIVER_HOST'] : 'localhost';
```

В документации написанно, что env хранит окружение, как это понимать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В линуксе (да и в windows тоже) есть такая штука -- [переменные окружения](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/slackware/#SHELL-BASH-ENVIRONMENT), и вот таким способом их можно читать.

То есть, можно в консоли набрать

```
export MONGO_NODE_DRIVER_HOST='127.0.0.1'
node server.js
```

И в вашей программе переменная host станет равна '127.0.0.1'

Answer (score 0):

Не окружение, а среда. ENViroment. Грубо говоря, настройки.

Постарайтесь читать на [английском](http://docs.stackato.com/deploy/languages/node.html), хоть это и непросто вначале. Меньше будет вопросов из-за перевода.

Comment: > Не окружение, а среда. ENViroment.

В русских переводах это синонимы.

Comment: Возможно. Но слово окружение вводит меня в ступор, а среда - нет.
Окружение для меня ambient %word%

Comment: По-моему это "среда окружения". Кстати, в nodejs есть замечательный пакет dotenv, позволяющий с легкостью работать с .env файлом в проекте. А импортировать переменные среды окружения я советую так: `const { HOST, PORT } = process.env`